# QML condition logic for updating a property

Tags: qt, qml, logic, conditional-statements

I am searching for a logic, so that an Image source property is changed depending on some different conditions.

I have created a small example with three conditions and three requirements build by those conditions.

If a requirement is active I want to see its picture in the Image area.
If a requirement is not active I do not want to see its image in the image area.
If two requirements would be active at the same time, it is ok to see just one of them.

I have problems with the code, because in case one requirement gets inactive and another gets active at the same time, the last requirement will control the content. But I want to have a higher priority on showing an image than not showing an image.

Is there any frequent way how to solve this?

I have the following code:

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property bool condition1: false
    property bool condition2: false
    property bool condition3: false

    Image{
        id: image
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: 120
        height: 120
        source: ""
    }

    Row {
        anchors.top: image.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        Button {
            id: button1
            text: "Condition1 = " + condition1
            onClicked: condition1 = !condition1
        }
        Button {
            id: button2
            text: "Condition2 = " + condition2
            onClicked: condition2 = !condition2
        }
        Button {
            id: button3
            text: "Condition3 = " + condition3
            onClicked: condition3 = !condition3
        }
    }

    StateObserver{
        condition: condition1 && condition2 && condition3
        bitmap: "Images/1.png"
        target: image
    }
    StateObserver{
        condition: !condition1 && condition2 && condition3
        bitmap: "Images/2.png"
        target: image
    }
    StateObserver{
        condition: !condition1 && !condition2 && condition3
        bitmap: "Images/3.png"
        target: image
    }
}
```

StateObserver.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {

    property bool condition

    property string bitmap

    property var target

    onConditionChanged: {
        if (condition){
        target.source = bitmap
        }
        else {
            target.source = ""
        }

        console.log("Change bitmap: " + bitmap)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not consider this a sound approach, as the order of binding expression evaluation is unspecified.

What I would do is have a single point that evaluates all possible combinations and use its result to rig the rest of the properties.

Through your `StateObserver` you are basically introducing unnecessary complexity. You also don't account for every possible state configuration.

You could simply:

```
  Image {
    id: image
    //...
    source: {
      if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) return "Images/1.png"
      else if (!condition1 && condition2 && condition3) return "Images/2.png"
      else if (!condition1 && !condition2 && condition3) return "Images/3.png"
      else return ""
    } 
  }
```

That's less code and less objects, meaning lower ram and cpu usage.

But if you insist on using your current approach, you can use `Binding` elements which can automatically toggle on or off using their `when` property.

Finally, you can also use QML's own [state machine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-state.html), although for such a trivial case that would be overkill.

Comment: Thanks dtech! Actually one requirement (StateObserver-Object) would be way more complex and I would have up to 50 of them. I think it might get unclear putting everything in the Image-source property directly. I think bindings could be exactly what I need.

Comment: Unfortunately Binding has the same problem like my method posted above. In case of binding is inactive, the image will contain the last content of the binding, but I want to get the image source going back to "" in case no binding is active.

Comment: Then you should add a binding `Binding on source { value: ""; when: someBooleanExpressionThatIsTrueWhenNoOtherBindingIsActive}` - something like that last line in the binding of *dtech*

Answer (score 0):

By the comment of dtech I have created an example using states. This works like expected and I am able to separate the states(requirements) from the main.qml(Layout). Thanks!

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainApp
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property bool condition1: false
    property bool condition2: false
    property bool condition3: false

    Image{
        id: image

        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: 120
        height: 120

        Img_StateList{
            container: image
        }
    }


    Row {
        anchors.top: image.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        Button {
            id: button1
            text: "Condition1 = " + condition1
            onClicked: condition1 = !condition1
        }
        Button {
            id: button2
            text: "Condition2 = " + condition2
            onClicked: condition2 = !condition2
        }
        Button {
            id: button3
            text: "Condition3 = " + condition3
            onClicked: condition3 = !condition3
        }
    }
}
```

Img_StateList.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    property Image container;
    state: "default"
    states: [
        State {
            name: "default"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: container
                source: ''
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "Img1"
            when: condition1 && condition2 && condition3
            PropertyChanges {
                target: container
                source: 'Images/1.png'
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "Img2"
            when: !condition1 && condition2 && condition3
            PropertyChanges {
                target: container
                source: 'Images/2.png'
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "Img3"
            when: !condition1 && !condition2 && condition3
            PropertyChanges {
                target: container
                source: 'Images/3.png'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```